is there a way to avoid removing line breaks while removing extra spaces from a text file?
for example i am using :
string.replace(/\s+/g, " ").trim();  // here string being my string name

it replaces all extra spaces with a single space along with line breaks as well.
But i want the line breaks to stay as they are while the extra spaces in a line to be replaced with a single space

Don't use \s use your own character grouping [ \t] or something (whatever the right answer is for you).

See Is there a JavaScript regular expression to remove all whitespace except newline?

As long as you don't narrow it down further I would use @Pointy's recommendation (space and tab) but [ \t]{2,} to avoid any redundant replacement of single spaces.

You could use the following negative character class trick here:
string = string.replace(/[^\S\n]+/g, " ").trim();

The pattern [^\S\n]+ matches:

Not \S, which is equivalent to \s (what you currently have)
But also not \n, which spares newlines from being replaced


The question only says "line breaks": Won't this strip carriage returns from files with Windows newlines?

@jsejcksn Windows line endings are not newlines, they are CRLF, i.e. \r\n.  I interpreted the OP's language literally.  If someone is using Windows and they are sure that \r would only appear in a CRLF, then a simple patch to the above answer would be to add \r to the negative character class.

^ @TimBiegeleisen Yeah — just observing that the question is underspecified in regard to what constitutes a "line break" (whether that's simply a line feed or also CRLF, etc.)

i dont know what windows lines are but yeah i do want the line breaks(\n) in a text file to remain as they are and only trim the edges of a line and remove any extra spaces in between.
I tried the code you mentioned but it just leaves the file untouched nothing changes

@Prabhat You need to assign the replacement expression back to the original string, with the latter being on the LHS, q.v. my updated answer.

@TimBiegeleisen Yes i did that but it doesn't work. although my previous expression was working fine just that it removes the line breaks as well

Getting closer: The pattern needs a + quantifier, use: [^\S\n]+

@TimBiegeleisen oh!! yes it works fine now great. Thanks a lot man helped a lot.
